# Bounding box labels are not visible

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I am using the TensorFlow object detection API. My training goes well, but when I test my image, the label size is not even visible. I have increased the font size to 30 from the default size 24 inside `draw_bounding_box_on_image()` in visualization_utils.py

```py
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 30)
```

But still the font size is not getting changed and the label is not visible at all.

This guy has given a solution but I don't know where to apply that solution.

[image]

How can I change the DPI = 100?

Comment: maybe first try font size like `150`?

Comment: @furas I changed the font size to 150 but the label is still not visible to me. how should i change the label so that at least it is visible somehow. but it is very small and not visible at all

Comment: if with 150 label is still not visible then you have something wrong with code. Maybe you set font in one place but later you use different font with wrong size. Or you set sizze in one file but later you run code in different file. Without full code it is impossible to say what make problem

Comment: I am using ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz model. I have installed with different methods, it worked on ubuntu and I have my labels and detections perfectly. But my gpu stopped working so now I am using colab to access gpu. Now its detecting perfectly but will low font size.